# Get an attachment from gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get with attachmentid

Tags: gmail-api

I am using gmailAPI to read an email message. From the JSON returned, I get an attachmentId and then I query gapi.client.gmail.messages.attachments.get to get the attachment itself. I am testing the code below with a png attachment and I do get JSON back and the data attribute I assume is base64 because that is what the header says

//Yes, I know the code below could be better but for now I am trying to figure what is contained in data.

```
function getAttachmentContent(attachmentDict, attachmentId, isLast) {

    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
        'userId': 'me',
        'messageId': getParameterByName('msgid'),
        'id': attachmentId
    });

    request.execute(function (resp) {
        attachmentDict[attachmentId].gmailAttachmentItem.Length = resp.size;
        attachmentDict[attachmentId].gmailAttachmentItem.Content = resp.data;

        if (isLast) {
            //Return only the key values as an array.
            var attachmentArray = new Array();
            for (key in attachmentDict) {
                if(key.indexOf("index") < 0)
                    attachmentArray.push(attachmentDict[key].gmailAttachmentItem);
            }

            emailMessage.GmailAttachments = attachmentArray.slice(0, attachmentArray.length - 1);
        }

    });
}
```

The JSON fragment which contains the attachmentid

```
{
"partId": "1",
"mimeType": "image/png",
"filename": "unnamed.png",
"headers": [
 {
  "name": "Content-Type",
  "value": "image/png; name=\"unnamed.png\""
 },
 {
  "name": "Content-Description",
  "value": "unnamed.png"
 },
 {
  "name": "Content-Disposition",
  "value": "attachment; filename=\"unnamed.png\"; size=13258; creation-date=\"Mon, 29 Aug 2016 13:34:23 GMT\"; modification-date=\"Mon, 29 Aug 2016 13:34:24 GMT\""
 },
 {
  "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
  "value": "base64"
 }
],
"body": {
 "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ8d3DgMc6114J2v-R16nU1biO2et7xOQZuC23BQgIXVq7v8mn-Ssn88I_zD-HOo6ArbKmv7vFe-1mkZKjNVkLPqP1n8wwhCgON-wh_BFkrArBkIU6SWN4Zh2uvKY2FQLIyCcJtyHDmZlgZB8b4MlLGiBXldpLJ0ioTH4f3De9YVuq5AxhioxbS9X2bggN2tT4YOZgXknVpBvsZ0O00Z43jAB92g3xMFqJjYeLN_l-vL0Xb73WY-xtwXWLGAPWlyD0wPq6a4Fi-qX_RWTfwMZN12AtGaLFFyrtGEKSfEo1cLKzYN8VosPPSVZHA",
 "size": 18146
    }
}
```

I get this response and the content in data is it base64 image?

I am using jsfiddle link to show the data because pasting the entire response exceeds the 30000 characters limit.

The content in the data attribute is base64 image? If not, what is it? According to Google

**attachmentid**: When present, contains the ID of an external attachment that can be retrieved in a separate messages.attachments.get request. When not present, the entire content of the message part body is contained in the data field.

**size**: Total number of bytes in the body of the message part.

**data**: The body data of a MIME message part. May be empty for MIME container types that have no message body or when the body data is sent as a separate attachment. An attachment ID is present if the body data is contained in a separate attachment.

The size I get back when I download an email message 18146 is different from the attachment size 13258. Attachmentid is present, so I should get the attachment when I use gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get but the size is different?

How do I get the image which is attached to the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're calling with message.get(format=FULL) currently?  In that case the "attachmentid" can be supplied to a separate message.attachment.get() call to retrieve the attachment content.  You can, alternatively, just call message.get(format=RAW) to retrieve the entire email, unparsed, in a single response.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Eric. Yes, I am using format=FULL which is the default. I do want, the subject, body, from email, and the time stamp of the email received and the FULL format helps. If I use RAW then I would have to decode base64 string and parse all the  info I need. I eventually need the attachment as a byte array to send it to a different web service. I am building a gmail contextual gadget. I feel like I am close with message.attachments.get but I cannot figure out what is the data, it does not look like the image I am expecting.

Comment: If there's an attachmentid field in the part.body then yes, use the messages.attachments.get() method on that attachmentid, to retrieve the attachment content.  That data is base64url encoded of whatever the actual attachment data is.  (So if the attachment is a image/png, once you attachments.get() and base64url decode, then the bytes you have will be the .png image bytes.  I'm not sure about the size difference, might be related to differences between original encoding in the email and how it's stored un-encoded in backend.)

Comment: Thanks Eric!! By any chance would you happen to know if gadget type="url" is supported? Here https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#writing_the_gadget_spec the documentation says that only type="html" is supported but here https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/fundamentals#Content_Type it says the type="url" content type is currently not fully supported by the gadgets.* or OpenSocial APIs. My gadget of type html adds an iframe to load the app. Here is my open question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128036/gmail-contextual-gadget-does-not-work-when-content-type-is-url